# How to create Nexus 5 emulator in Windows with 2 GB RAM?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I want to create a Nexus 5 emulator in my Windows system with 2 GB RAM. But default Nexus 5 emulator requires 2 GB RAM. I edited RAM size and used 1024M and created Nexus 5 emulator. But it is not loading. And I am not able to use that emulator.

How can I create Nexus 5 emulator with low RAM size?

Comment: `I edited RAM size and used 1024M and created Nexus 5 emulator.` Still too much - try **512 MB**.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks for your fast response. Even if i use 1024M also the emulator is not working. Then how can i go for 512M?

Comment: When you create an emulator you can specify the RAM size (I assume you're using Eclipse - I don't know Android Studio, but it should be a similar process)

Comment: I would suggest you to try Genymotion emulator, and download new device (nexus 5) within it it works with 2GB as RAM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Goto: `C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<avd-profile-name>.avd\config.ini` and change the entry

`hw.ramSize=2048` to `hw.ramSize=2048MB`

Comment: Thanks for response N1C0. What does it means ranSize=2048MB ?

Comment: Oh my bad. Should have been `ramSize=2048MB`